# Upgrading SaltStack Master & Minion if installed using bootstrap script

Tags: saltstack

As the title stated, how do I upgrade SaltStack (both Master and Minion) if I installed them using the `bootstrap.sh` script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the `bootstrap.sh` scripts installs the stable version of SaltStack. Depending on your OS you can upgrade SaltStack using you package manager.

For example on you salt-master (OS: Ubuntu) you might run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade salt-master
```

On your salt-master you can get a list of what version of SaltStack your minsions are running:

```
sudo salt '*' test.version
```

To get a list of up-to-date minions and those that need updating, you can run the following command on your salt-master:

```
sudo salt-run manage.versions
```

You can use SaltStack to upgrade all of your salt-minions at once:

```
sudo salt '*' pkg.install salt-minion refresh=True
```

An alternative method would be to use the apt commands like this:

```
sudo salt -G 'os:Ubuntu' cmd.run "apt-get -y install salt-minion"
```

Verify that everything is upgraded by running `sudo salt '*' test.version` again.